# How to create bindings qml to d?

Tags: qt, binding, qml, d

I want to use qml with d language. But there is not bindings to d, and I want to create it. But I don't know how to begin. Tell me, please, how to begin to create bindings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since nobody answered:

From what I understand `QML` is the modelling language of `Qt` and I guess it depends heavily on `Qt`. I assume here it depends on `Qt`, at least to some extend.

First of all there was already an attempt to bind `Qt` to `D`: http://www.dsource.org/projects/qtd, but from what I've heared this project is kinda dead and not developed anylonger (last commit 2 years ago). You could use it as base for your work or as a reference on how you *could* bind `QML` and `Qt`.

### 1. Option, a C/C++ Glue-Layer

A C-Glue Layer means, you write your code basically twice. You write a complete `C++` to `C` wrapper in `C++` (the language which can directly interface with `Qt` and `Qml`). That means you wrap every method of a class inside a `C` function which takes a Pointer (to a struct representing this `C++ Qt class`). This could look like this (note this is an abstraction of GtkWebkit, which is written in C, but the snippet demonstrates how to do it quite well):

```
// somewhere in a header
typedef struct SurfiClient {
    GtkWidget *window; // Offscreen window
    // ....
}

typedef GdkPixbuf Pixbuf;

extern "C" {
    Pixbuf* surfi_client_get_pixbuf(SurfiClient* client)
    {
        // in C++ this would gtk_offscreen_window_get_pixbuf would be a method of client->window
        return gtk_offscreen_window_get_pixbuf(GTK_OFFSCREEN_WINDOW(client->window));
    }

    // here go the rest of these functions, probably thousands
}
```

You have to basically do this for everything you want to interface later on from the D side. Even worse you have to also do it for `namespaces` and free functions which are not marked `extern "C"`, this could look like this ([`libsquish`](https://code.google.com/p/libsquish/)):

```
typedef unsigned char u8;
extern "C" {
     void CompressMasked(u8 const* rgba, int mask, void* block, int flags) {                    
         squish::CompressMasked(rgba, mask, block, flags);
     }
}
```

As you can see by now, this is quite tedious...

Let's assume you have finished making the `C/C++` Glue-Layer, now you have to create code in `D` which can interface it.

To stay with the `gtk` example:

```
extern(C) {
    // Using an opaque struct is one option
    struct SurfiClient;

    // the other is to wrap the struct correctly
    struct SurfiClient {
        GtkWidget *window;
    }

    // The Pixbuf was only a typedef to GdkPixbuf which is already an opaque data structure, easy
    struct Pixbuf;


    Pixbuf* surfi_client_get_pixbuf(SurfiClient* client);
}
```

You see in this example a problem, if you want to wrap the `SurfiClient` struct correctly, you also have to wrap `GtkWidget` or do it incorrectly and use `void*` instead of `GtkWidget*`, which is no real soloution to the problem. You will most likely also run into this problem, you Glue-Layer struct has members which you don't have abstractions for, I would go here with the opaque struct and provide functions for the members which are really needed for the user.

I am not going more into detail on how to interface with C, there are already a few guides:

1. http://dlang.org/interfaceToC.html
2. http://www.gamedev.net/blog/1140/entry-2254003-binding-d-to-c/
3. https://github.com/D-Programming-Deimos (Not a guide but a collection of C bindings, could be used as reference)

The last step in the process of makind `Qt`, `Qml` bindings would be to rebuild the `OOP-Api` in `D` based on your newly made `C-Bindings`.

### 2. Option, [`SWIG`](http://www.swig.org/)/Binding generator

I am not an expert with [`SWIG`](http://www.swig.org/), that's the reason why I am only covering it in a few sentences.

What you can use `SWIG` for is generate the whole `C/C++-Glue Layer thingy` for you. If you're lucky, your `SWIG-File` only consists of a few `includes` to `Qt` and `SWIG` will do all the work for you. If not, you have to define rules for `Classes` and `Functions` on your own, which can be tedious (but also easier and faster than doing `1. Option`). So `SWIG` is definitly worth a try!

As a side-note: If you have a template/macro/ heavy/Header only `C++` Library like [`glm`](http://glm.g-truc.net/) `SWIG` can be tricky or in case of `glm` no option.

There are alternative Binding-Generators, e.g. the [PySide](https://qt-project.org/wiki/PySide) Project started with `Boost.Python` then switched to [`Shiboken`](https://shiboken.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). I don't know how easily you can generate bindings with `Shiboken` for anything else than `CPython`, maybe hacking into `Shiboken` or even `Boost.Python` could work? Also worth a read: http://setanta.wordpress.com/binding-c/.

`QtD` used [QtJambi](http://qt-jambi.org/doc/generator) so this might be a good start.

### 3. Option, the D way

D has the great idea of having `extern(C++)`, which allows in theory making `C++/D` bindings without such a Glue-Layer: http://dlang.org/cpp_interface.html.

Nice idea, but unfortunatly too limited. E.g. there is no support for namespaces yet (there is an open issue on bugzilla, I can't find right now). In my opinion `extern(C++)` is too limited for Qt.

Manu Evans mentioned in his [first talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FKceA691Wcg) at the [D conference](http://dconf.org) how to bind to `C++` from D sucessfully with using `D`s metaprogramming capabilities.

### In a nutshell

- A `C/C++` Glue-Layer gives you the most flexibility, it will work, but is no simple and especially a long task (I would do this for rather small projects).
- SWIG/Binding generators, the way I would go for `Qt`, once correctly setup they do all the work for you (in the best case).
- `extern(C++)`, nice idea, too limited for most serious `C++` projects.

I hope this gives you a short overview of what you can do and the amount of work it requires.

Answer (score 1):

they are already an article on this purpose [how to interface C code to D?](http://dlang.org/interfaceToC.html)

Usually is not hard. Take function declaration and put it into an `extern(C)` block

And usually these module are written into a c package. Example:

```
src/
`-- appName
    |-- c
    |   `-- dInterface.d
    `-- dwrapper.d
```

The module `appName.c.dInterface` will define C function with an `extern(C)` block
While the module a`ppName.dwrapper` will provide a way that fit more with dlang.

Comment: Only that this won't work with QML since Qt is entirely written in C++ and Ds `extern(C++)` is far from beeing complete. Having a glue-layer between would be possible, using swig probably also. But neither of these appraoches is easy and especially not fast to complete.